# How do I count how many times a string occur in a file using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to count no. of occurrences of a regex string or a html tag in the entire file using javascript?
Say for example, I want to find how many `<a href="graphic[0-9]+">` tags are present in a file and store that value in a variable. How do I achieve that?

Comment: In what environment, browser or other?

Answer (score 0):

```
var len = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='graphic[0-9]+']").length;
```

Comment: Can this be used in a UltraEdit script?

Comment: Have not tried UltraEdit, though there should be some feature which searches for text within current document. Question is not related to `javascript` if `javascript` is not used.

Comment: It has javascript engine built-in

Comment: Then you can use `.querySelectorAll()` with element and attribute selector as demonstrated at Answer

Comment: And what about searching for a normal string in the entire file, say "abc123"?

Comment: You can use `.match()` with appropriate `RegExp` `var len = document.documentElement.outerHTML.match(/abc123/g).length`